# Tag friend on Photo like in Facebook

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

Now I'm working on social network (ASP.NET MVC 3). And I want to add "tag friends on this photo" functionality.
I have AlbumController. In this controller I have an action TagFriend.
Signature of this action:

```
public ActionResult TagFriend(Guid friendId, int imageId /*some parameters that describe the area that is marked friend*/)
{
// TODO
}
```

Question is 
1. what parameters, which describe area is marked friend, should I transmit to action of controller.
2. What jQuery libraries can help me?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic principle is that you need to add a draggable/resizable div on an image. when the user finally commits to a setting for the div you need to save the 4 coordinates or the corners and the size of the div that's associated with a string value which is the tag.

There are endless implementation of this out there which surprises me how you ended up making a stack question of it as googling it takes about 3 seconds. but here you go:

1. http://djpate.com/2011/01/14/jtag-a-jquery-plugin-to-tag-pictures-more/
2. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1839-jQuery-Photo-Tagger-Plugin-For-Flickr-Style-Photo-Tagging.htm
3. http://karlmendes.com/2010/07/jquery-photo-tag-plugin/
   and many more...

'Search term' : jQuery photo tagging